# Nomethod error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models  **PrdItem**   and **PrdAllislandFlatDelivery**

The models are in one to one relationship as below

**prd_item.rb**

```
has_one :prd_allisland_flat_delivery, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :prd_item
accepts_nested_attributes_for   :prd_allisland_flat_delivery, allow_destroy: true
```

**prd_allisland_flat_delivery.rb**

```
belongs_to :prd_item
```

**prd_items_controller.rb**

```
@item = PrdItem.new
@item.prd_allisland_flat_delivery.build
```

this give me the following error:

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `has_one-belongs_to` association, we should be using `main_object.build_related_object`.

In your case,

```
@item.build_prd_allisland_flat_delivery
```

This should work.